# Aurelia select multiple doesn't bind the value while select does

Tags: javascript, select, binding, aurelia

I faced some very strange thing. I have select and select multiple elements. When I first load the page with the form, and change selected options in select multiple, it doesn't bind new value to a variable in select multiple (although it binds correctly if it is just select, not multiple). But then if I do something on the page that requires updating data in the form (for example, I push the button Revert that loads data in the form from db), it starts binding new selected options in select multiple. I am confused

For example:

```
<select multiple class="form-control input-sm" value.bind="workers">
    <option repeat.for="option of selectors.worker" model.bind="option.value" disabled.bind="option.disabled">
      ${option.name}
    </option>
  </select>
  ${workers}
```

${workers} is not updated if I change selected options

Comment: A new issue is opened https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say to use `model.bind` for select multiple. Therefore, the select should be like this:

```
<select multiple='multiple' value.two-way="selectedThings" style="width: 100%">
   <option repeat.for="thing of things" model.bind="thing">${thing.name}</option>
</select>
```

However, the changes in `selectedThings` don't seem to be reflected on the view. I believe that's because of the way aurelia sets the bound value internally. We should wait for an answer of the team to understand why this happen. In the mean time, I could solve this using the a getter property that dirty-checks `selectedThings`. Like this:

```
get myThings() {
   return this.selectedThings.map(thing => thing.name).join(',');
   //or just return this.selectedThings
}
```

Running example: https://gist.run/?id=5a9c5cda449bfe3789a58122372a0a20

### **EDIT**

If you want to use select2 you can manipulate everything inside select2 custom attribute. Like this:

**Custom Attribute**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {customAttribute} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {DOM} from 'aurelia-pal';
import {TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-task-queue';


@inject(DOM.Element, TaskQueue)
@customAttribute('ddl')
export class Select2CustomAttribute {

  constructor(element, taskQueue) {
    this.element = element;
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  bind(bindingContext) {
    this.bindingContext = bindingContext;
  }

  attached() {
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
      this.create();
    });
  }

  create() {
    //Object.assign(defaultOpts, this.options);
    $(this.element).select2()
      .on('change', (evt) => {
        if (evt.originalEvent) {
          return;
        }
        this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));

        //reset value to avoid multiple-select problems
        let value = this.bindingContext[this.element.getAttribute('value.bind')];
        this.bindingContext[this.element.getAttribute('value.bind')] = [];
        this.bindingContext[this.element.getAttribute('value.bind')] = value;
      });
  }

}
```

**USAGE**

```
<require from="./select2-attribute"></require>

  <select style="width: 200px;" ddl value.bind="selectedValue" change.delegate="valueChanged()" multiple>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
```

Running Example: https://gist.run/?id=2189fda060e77e3f735ce59528df79b8

If you need dynamic options you have to destroy and create select2 again or something like that (I have some examples you if you want).

Comment: Your solution works but I need select multiple to work properly without extra requirements (like dirty checking of each element or assigning data to variables the second time in attached() once the page is loaded) as a singe select works. I want to combine this select multiple element with a custom attribute (select2)

Comment: You should've told that before. See my edit answer and take a look at this gist https://gist.run/?id=2189fda060e77e3f735ce59528df79b8

Comment: thank you, sorry for not mentioning custom attribute, it works